# Mail command using alternative SMTP port?

Tags: linux, smtp, email

I have setup an SMTP server on port 10025. I wanted to test sending emails to it via the command line.

Is there a parameter I can give the mail command to use the smtp server on 10025?

```
echo hello | mail -s'testing' myemail@address.com ???
```

I do have a seperate smtp server running on port 25 as well but I don't want to be communicating with that one or switch it off.

Thanks for you time,
Mark

Comment: `mail` does not use SMTP. It just calls `/usr/bin/sendmail`, which takes care of delivery.

Comment: You can add sendmail parameters to it though via -f, can't you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For testing, just telnet to the port: cf. [this sample SMTP](http://www.telecom.otago.ac.nz/tele301/student_html/speak-smtp.html).

**Postscript**
If you want a one-liner, put the following with the requisite arguments in your path:

```
#!/bin/bash
from=$1; to=$2
echo EHLO $from
echo MAIL FROM: $from
echo RCPT TO: $to
echo DATA
echo Subject: Test $from $to
echo
echo Test message body.
echo .
```

And then pipe that script, with its two arguments, into telnet localhost 10025

Comment: Looks like you beat me...I like your page better, anyway.

Comment: It just seems a shame that I couldn't have a 1-line command sitting in a bash script.  Do you know of any other command-line smtp tools for sending?  I've resorted to a PHP script for the moment :(